# Security issue on raspberry pi: too many open connections?

Tags: archlinux, networking, security

I have just run `netstat` on my raspberry pi and found out there more than 100 (!) open connections. Is this something I should be worried about? How do I stop my rasp pi from opening so many connections?

I have arch linux installed on it.

Comment: Wow, paste the output.

Comment: maybe its updates? :)

Comment: Yes, where are the connections to?

Comment: Do a `sudo netstat -a --program` to see which PID / program opened the connection.

Comment: Post the daemons enabled. Maybe it's SSH?

Comment: Are you sure these are actual connections, vs services which are listening?  netstat will also by default display the unix domain sockets which are purely internal to the system.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: these were actual connections. Running `sudo netstat -a --program` helped me identify the problem.

Comment: @pap42 - so what inappropriate actual connection to a remote system did you find?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: they were actually not inappropriate; they belonged to daemons which I forgot to disable weeks ago (and consequently forgot entirely about their existence).

Comment: And there were remote systems actually connected to them?  Or only sockets listening (which are _not_ connections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the following command to see which PID (Process ID) / Program opened the connection:

```
sudo netstat -a --program

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:9090                  *:*                     LISTEN      1016/xbmc.bin
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN      825/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      1016/xbmc.bin
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN      741/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      727/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:36666                 *:*                     LISTEN      1016/xbmc.bin
tcp        0      0 *:36667                 *:*                     LISTEN      1016/xbmc.bin
tcp        0      0 37L4247F26-13:ssh       jpm-lt:54418            ESTABLISHED 3477/sshd: pi [priv
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN      825/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      727/sshd
udp        0      0 *:45593                 *:*                                 442/dhclient
udp        0      0 *:9777                  *:*                                 1016/xbmc.bin
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 442/dhclient
udp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                                 825/rpcbind
udp        0      0 37L4247F26-13:ntp       *:*                                 736/ntpd
udp        0      0 raspbmc:ntp             *:*                                 736/ntpd
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*                                 736/ntpd
udp        0      0 *:987                   *:*                                 825/rpcbind
udp        0      0 *:43753                 *:*                                 731/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                 731/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 [::]:26705              [::]:*                              442/dhclient
udp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                              825/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 raspbmc:ntp             [::]:*                              736/ntpd
udp6       0      0 fe80::ba27:ebff:fea:ntp [::]:*                              736/ntpd
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                              736/ntpd
udp6       0      0 [::]:35477              [::]:*                              731/avahi-daemon: r
```

Comment: You forgot to put the command.